# Why my for loop is not drawing multiple repeated shapes in the html canvas sketch?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, html5-canvas

```
<html>
<body>
    <canvas width = "1200" height = "1200"> </canvas>


    <script>

        let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        let context = canvas.getContext('2d');


        context.fillStyle = '#5bd75b';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 1200, 1200);

        let radius = 500;
        for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
          if (Math.random() >= 0.5)
          {
            context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
          }
          else
          {
            context.fillStyle = 'red';
          }
          context.arc(600, 600, radius / i, 0, Math.PI * 2);
          context.fill(); 
         }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to draw multiple circles which will get smaller as the loop runs, but all I get is one big circle, can you please find what's wrong with my code or logic? I'm tired of trying things and finding a solution because my loop's format seems to be right.

Comment: You might want to review[ask]

Comment: See [Why does the Canvas API fill parts of these paths within a loop with the wrong color?](/a/69730036/4642212). `fill` fills paths, `arc` creates subpaths of the same path. You need `beginPath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using canvas path functions you need to specify when a path begins and when it ends.
If not done so, all `context.arc` calls will be merged together into one big path which will be filled every time with the last given color.

Heres the solution to your problem:

```js
context.beginPath();
context.arc(600, 600, radius / i, 0, Math.PI * 2);
context.fill();
context.closePath();
```

Comment: `context.closePath();` is superfluous. It only connects the current subpath to its starting point. An `arc` with raidus `Math.PI * 2` is already closed.